# Reducing Size of Case Statement

Tags: case, formula-field

```
CASE( 
RegisteringCountry 
,"Argentina", "India",
"Australia", "India",
"Bangladesh", "Singapore",
"Belgium", "India",
"Bhutan", "Singapore",
"Brunei Darussalam","Singapore",
"Brazil", "India",
"Cameroon", "India",
"Canada", "India",
"Chile", "India",
"China", "Singapore",
"Czech Republic", "India", 
"Denmark", "India",
"Egypt", "Singapore",
"England", "India",
"Ethiopia", "Singapore",
"France", "India",
"Germany", "India",
"Greece", "India",
"Hong Kong", "Singapore",
"India", "Singapore",
"Indonesia", "Singapore",
"Iran", "Singapore",
"Ireland", "India",
"Italy", "India",
"Japan", "Singapore",
"Jordan", "Singapore",
"Kenya", "India",
"Kingdom of Saudi Arabia", "Singapore",
"Korea", "Singapore",
"Laos", "Singapore",
"Malaysia", "Singapore",
"Mauritius", "India",
"Morocco", "India",
"Myanmar", "Singapore",
"New Zealand", "New Zealand",
"Nigeria", "India",
"Oman", "Singapore",
"Pakistan", "Singapore",
"Palestine", "Singapore",
"Papua New Guinea", "India",
"Philippines", "Singapore",
"Poland", "India",
"Portugal", "India",
"Russia", "India",
"Saudi Arabia", "Singapore",
"Singapore", "Singapore",
"South Africa", "India",
"South Korea", "Singapore",
"Sri Lanka", "Singapore",
"Sweden", "India",
"Switzerland", "India",
"Taiwan", "Singapore",
"Thailand", "Singapore",
"United Arab Emirates", "Singapore",
"UAE", "Singapore",
"United Kingdom", "India",
"USA", "India",
"Vietnam", "Singapore",
"Zambia", "India", "")
```

I'm new to Sales Force and have reached the max limit on the field. IS there any way to reduce the size of the code. I was thinking of using if else but can't get it to work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where you are using this statement, is that in formula field or validation rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, probably the easiest and most straight-forward approach here would be to take advantage of the "default" action of the `Case` formula function.

Form [the documentation on formula functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5)

> ### CASE
>
> ### Description:
>
> Checks a given expression against a series of values. If the expression is equal to a value, returns the corresponding result. If it is not equal to any values, it returns the else_result.
>
> ### Use:
>
> `CASE(expression,​value1, result1, value2,​ result2,...,​ else_result)` and replace expression with the field or value you want compared to each specified value. Replace each value and result with the value that must be equivalent to return the result entry. Replace else_result with the value you want returned when the expression does not equal any values.

In your situation, you only have 2 output values, "India" and "Singapore".
Choose one, keep all the lines in your `CASE` that you want to map to your one location (say, India), and then use the default value to populate your other target location (Singapore in this example) for all of your other countries.